# Alert sound with no pop-up from google calendar on android

Tags: notifications, google-calendar

On my Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra (Android 13) phone I'm getting the default notification alert sound but no pop-up.  I had been getting the alert for a while.  To track it down I turned off notifications for all of my apps and then started turning them back on one at a time.  Determined that it was coming from google calendar. There's nothing in Notification History or the Notification Panel when I get the alert.  It happens all day long.  Anyone have any ideas.

**Problem solved:** Suggestions from another forum said turn off notification reminders. That solved the problem. I'm not sure why you would get notification reminders when notifications are turned off but apparently that's how it works.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider post it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed, but even encouraged!](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!